# Let $K\subseteq L$ be a subfield show there exists $\alpha\in L$ such that $L=K[\alpha]$, $L$ is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that $K[\alpha]= \{\sum_{i=0}^nc_i\alpha^i|n\in\mathbb{N},c_i\in K\}$. How can I start, what should I do first? I have to show that for every Element in $L$ one can describe it as $\sum_{i=0}^n1$ because I have noticed that since this subfield can be chosen arbitrarily it can also be the field with only two elements.

Comment: Any finite field has a cyclic multiplicative group of units. Therefore choosing the generator of the group to be $\alpha$ would do.

Comment: If $L/K$ is non-separable then it may fail. Otherwise it is the primitive element theorem.